# How does the electric field pattern looks like when current is moving inside the conductor and why this field is uniform?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electric-current

We know that electric field is uniform inside a normal electric circuit consisting of some battery source and a conducting wire , $\mathrm{E}$ will be $\mathrm{E=V/d}$ , but I cannot think of a reason as to why this field is uniform and also how this field $\mathrm{E}$ looks like inside the conducting circuit and outside too? Is it different from the stationary charge electric field?

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is potential difference $V$ on two ends of a conducting wire of length $d$ such that the electric field in the wire has a magnitude $E=V/d$?

Comment: Yeah right @Newbie

Answer (score 1):

It's known that in the static case (i.e., $\partial/\partial t=0$) there is no electric field inside a conductor. You can prove this for yourself by solving the continuity equation $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\vec J=0$ in a conductor where $\vec J=\sigma\vec E$. The higher the conductivity, the shorter the Maxwellian relaxation time $\frac{\epsilon_{0}}{\sigma}$ for the charge to spread on the **surface** of the conductor **as opposed to being inside of it**. Thus, there can be no electric field inside the wire and no electric potential on the two ends of the wire since the electric field on the surface of the wire will be perpendicular to the surface. However, the electrons will still drift through the surface of the wire with constant velocity as they will not accelerate or decelerate. Electrons will get the energy to circulate through the circuit when they pass the battery and they lose some energy when they pass through e.g., a resistor.

The specific relation $E=V/d$ that you provided often happens in modeling capacitors where two conducting plates are separated from each other at a distance $d$. It is an assumption that $E$ in the space between the plates is uniform, constant, and equal to $V/d$ where $V$ is the potential difference between the two plates. While the electric field may seem uniform in the interior sections of the plates, it definitely has curvature at the edges. Nonetheless, the fringing is considered negligible.

Comment: Thanks Sir this i got it but consider a simple circuit which i mentioned above with a resistance too if needed  , there current will flow  in the conductor now may you tell if the electric field will be inside as then only its possible for electrons to move isnt ? So current flowing is a non steady case isnt Sir ? And if all things i said above is true pls also show how the field lines look like inside and also outside too of the conductor?

Comment: Current flow can happen in steady case as well. A resistor is a wire with finite conductivity. You can apply a potential difference to the two end of the resistor and you will have steady constant current passing through it. In that case the electric field and current will both be parallel to the resistor.

Comment: i see thanks Sir . Is there some source which describes the electric field lines for a steady current flowing ? Like the shapes in various cases . And what is this electric field known as ?[ like i know for static conditions its known as electrostatic electric field and i know the shapes and other stuff in electrostatic conditions)]

Comment: Sir may you respond to my query ?